# How to use ActiveAndroid to retrieve data from pre-populated database?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I have tried to implement the ActiveAndroid on my project to read my existing database in my asset folder. I have performed query method and put it in my arraylist but it does not work. Please look into my code.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Array list for storing all the inventoryItems
private ArrayList<String> questionItems;

//Adapter for listview
private ArrayAdapter questionItemsAdapter;
private ListView listViewQuestion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);

    listViewQuestion = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewQuestion);

    //Initializing arraylist
    questionItems = new ArrayList<>();

    showList();
}

public static List<Questions> getAll() {
    return new Select()
            .from(Questions.class)
            .orderBy("question ASC")
            .execute();
}

private void showList() {
    //Creating a list and getting all questions from the method
    List<Questions> questions = getAll();

    //Adding all the items of the questions to arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
        Questions question = questions.get(i);
        questionItems.add(question.question);
    }

    //Creating our adapter
    questionItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, questionItems);

    //Adding adapter to listview
    listViewQuestion.setAdapter(questionItemsAdapter);

}
}
```

Questions.java:

```
@Table(name = "Questions")
public class Questions extends Model {

@Column (name = "question")
public String question;

@Column (name = "answer")
public String answer;

public Questions(){
    super();
}

public Questions(String question, String answer){
    super();
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}
}
```

The result shows only an empty space. Where did I do wrong?
I've been working on this pre-populated database for almost 2 months also by using other methods but I don't find the one that I need.

Comment: you are still using listviews @Ewo

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Nowadays we use RecyclerViews instead of ListViews

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Well, actually the list view is just for a test if my app can read the pre-populated database. Later if it's proven that the database can be read, I will not use it anymore. But I think I still need to put the data to ArrayList, don't I? What do you think?